# Pass parameter to Parent from Child component through props function call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There is the parent component

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");
    const onChangeQuery = (searchText) => {
        setSearchText(searchText);
    }
    return (
          <Child onChangeQuery={onChangeQuery} />
    )
}
```

And there is my child component

```
const Child = ({onChangeQuery}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     onChangeQuery(someText);
  }, [someChangingVariable]);

  return (
      <h1>Hello World!<h1/>
  )
}
```

But i am getting Unhandled Runtime Error. TypeError: onChangeQuery is not a function.

I am not able to resolve it.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is the code causing the error? I don't really see an issue with the snippet. Is this the complete code? The `Child` component appears to be missing a return. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes, child has return (i have skipped it). There i am stuck. I have searched everywhere but could not find the problem.

Comment: Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the error that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I didn't see any issue with your code, try to check the spelling of the `onChangeQuery`, and if not working try to provide more details  that we could debug